# How to define Hashmap in an XSD?

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to make an xsd file out of a json response that I have got and later using that xsd  to generate JAXB classes. My problem is that the json is in a format I am unable to convert to xsd. Here is my json :

```
{
"result1":[{"010201":[3,2,0,4,3,4]},{"010202":[1,6,3,2,2,2]},{"010203":[2,3,3,4,4,0]}],
"result2":[1,6,3,2,2,2],
"result3":[{"010201":[3,2,0,3,4]},{"010202":[1,6,3,2,2]},{"010203":[2,3,4,4,0]}],
"result4":[1,4,6,4,1],
"result5":[{"010201":34},{"010202":12},{"010203":78}],
"result6":41
}
```

Here is the above json in xml format :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<result1>
    <010201>3</010201>
    <010201>2</010201>
    <010201>0</010201>
    <010201>4</010201>
    <010201>3</010201>
    <010201>4</010201>
</result1>
<result1>
    <010202>1</010202>
    <010202>6</010202>
    <010202>3</010202>
    <010202>2</010202>
    <010202>2</010202>
    <010202>2</010202>
</result1>
<result1>
    <010203>2</010203>
    <010203>3</010203>
    <010203>3</010203>
    <010203>4</010203>
    <010203>4</010203>
    <010203>0</010203>
</result1>

<result2>1</result2>
<result2>6</result2>
<result2>3</result2>
<result2>2</result2>
<result2>2</result2>
<result2>2</result2>
<result3>
    <010201>3</010201>
    <010201>2</010201>
    <010201>0</010201>
    <010201>3</010201>
    <010201>4</010201>
</result3>
<result3>
    <010202>1</010202>
    <010202>6</010202>
    <010202>3</010202>
    <010202>2</010202>
    <010202>2</010202>
</result3>
<result3>
    <010203>2</010203>
    <010203>3</010203>
    <010203>4</010203>
    <010203>4</010203>
    <010203>0</010203>
</result3>
<result4>1</result4>
<result4>4</result4>
<result4>6</result4>
<result4>4</result4>
<result4>1</result4>
<result5>
    <010201>34</010201>
</result5>
<result5>
    <010202>12</010202>
</result5>
<result5>
    <010203>78</010203>
</result5>
<result6>41</result6>
```

I am facing no issues in creating complex types for result2, result4, result6 elements. But result1, result3 and result5 have an array of array of integers. How do i create  an xsd for that ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: XSDs are used to define contents of XML documents not json. Or I have understood the question incorrectly.

Comment: @dc.sashwat, json is just a data format, think of the above as an xml. We can define the same as an xml format. I have edited the question to include the xml for same as well.

Comment: Your "XML format" isn't XML, so it's useless (numeric element names aren't allowed). If some converter is generating that format, then the converter is useless. Chuck it out and find a better one.

Comment: @MichaelKay ok forget the xml. I know numeric names are not allowed. That was just an example.

Comment: When people post things that are wrong, one's immediate reaction is that the wrongness is at the heart of the problem. So don't do it!

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying an XSD to generate an XML like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <result1>
        <entry>
            <key>010201</key>
            <value>
                <val>3</val>
                <val>2</val>
                <val>1</val>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>010201</key>
            <value>
                <val>3</val>
                <val>2</val>
                <val>1</val>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </result1>
    <result2>
        <value>
            <val>3</val>
            <val>2</val>
            <val>1</val>
        </value>
    </result2>
    <result3>
        <entry>
            <key>010201</key>
            <value>
                <val>3</val>
                <val>2</val>
                <val>1</val>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>010201</key>
            <value>
                <val>3</val>
                <val>2</val>
                <val>1</val>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </result3>
    <result4>
        <value>
            <val>3</val>
            <val>2</val>
            <val>1</val>
        </value>
    </result4>
    <result5>
        <entry>
            <key>010201</key>
            <value>2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>010201</key>
            <value>2</value>
        </entry>
     </result5>
</root>
```

The xsd will be simpler for the above. Keeping the values as XML tags will not be feasible if the values will change.

Comment: This is not dynamic!

Comment: If your data format is not generic, or it cannot be made generic use xsd:any or cdata section in string to define your data. Anyway neither your XML provided is generic :D.

Comment: What you show in this answer is _not_ an XSD. It is an XML document. It is unclear what your intent is in the first place.

Comment: I am trying to help the user to create his XSD. The user seems capable of writing his own XSD, I am suggesting an XML format for which he can create the XSD. In my opinion the direction of his solution is incorrect and am trying to suggest alternates for the xml. How generic the xsd can be will depend on the data, whether result1, result 2 etc. willa lways have the same format.